# how do you make a JButton act like a static variable ie work in all methods

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, instance-variables

I have a JButton array
button[100]
and use is in more than one method, one creating the 100 buttons and one the action listener
i've used

```
String abc=button[i].setActionCommand(String.format("Button %d", i));
```

to find what button was pressed but variable button can't be identified.

Comment: `setActionCommand` returns void, nothing. You shouldn't try to set a String variable abc = void. As for your main problem, you've likely got a scope issue, but it's hard to say how to fix it with the limited information currently available to us in your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give your variable more than local method scope. If you define it as a instance variable of the class, it will be accessible anywhere inside that class.

```
class YourClass {

     private JButton[] buttons; // instance variable, accessible to all methods in class 

     public void foo() {
          buttons = new JButton[100]; // can use buttons here
     }

     public void bar() {
          // can also use buttons here
          for (JButton button : buttons) {  

         }
     }
}
```

Comment: thanks though i modified your method slightly, i just moved JButton button[100] out of the method map() and it's fixed thanks. I worked on that problem for 3 days, thank you for solving it!!!

Answer (score 1):

To find out in the `ActionListener` which button was pressed, you could ask the `ActionEvent` for its source (see [ActionEvent#getSource](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/EventObject.html#getSource%28%29)). This will be the button

Answer (score 0):

```
public class abc{

 JButton button[]=new JButton[100];

method

}
```